# How to give portal access to a Flatpak app using cli

Tags: flatpak

After installing and launching the app `com.tomjwatson.Emote` I get prompted to give it the Background portal access. I know I can toggle access to a portal conveniently via the Flatseal app, but I am looking for a solution that works from a bash script setting up a computer - with as little user GUI action as possible.

When manually giving access via Flatseal (presumably the same from the initial launch prompt), I get this output:

```
$ flatpak permission-show com.tomjwatson.Emote
Table      Object     App                  Permissions Data
background background com.tomjwatson.Emote yes         0x00
```

### How can I give access to that portal via the command line?

After reading the terse [documentation](https://flatpak-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/flatpak-command-reference.html#flatpak-permission-set) (I wish it had some examples), I tried some variations of the `flatpak permission-set` command:

```
$ flatpak permission-set background com.tomjwatson.Emote yes
$ flatpak permission-show com.tomjwatson.Emote

$ flatpak permission-set background com.tomjwatson.Emote
error: Too few arguments

See 'flatpak permission-set --help'
$ flatpak permission-set background com.tomjwatson.Emote background
$ flatpak permission-show com.tomjwatson.Emote

$ flatpak permission-set background com.tomjwatson.Emote background yes
$ flatpak permission-show com.tomjwatson.Emote

$ flatpak permission-set background com.tomjwatson.Emote --data=0x00
error: Too few arguments

See 'flatpak permission-set --help'
$ flatpak permission-set background com.tomjwatson.Emote background --data=0x00
$ flatpak permission-show com.tomjwatson.Emote

$ flatpak permission-set background com.tomjwatson.Emote background yes --data=0x00
$ flatpak permission-show com.tomjwatson.Emote

$ flatpak permission-set background com.tomjwatson.Emote yes --data=0x00
$ flatpak permission-show com.tomjwatson.Emote

$ flatpak permission-set background --data=0x00 com.tomjwatson.Emote
error: Too few arguments

See 'flatpak permission-set --help'
$ flatpak permission-set background --data=0x00 com.tomjwatson.Emote yes
$ flatpak permission-show com.tomjwatson.Emote

$ flatpak permission-set background --data=0x00 com.tomjwatson.Emote true
$ flatpak permission-show com.tomjwatson.Emote

$ flatpak permission-set background --data=0x00 com.tomjwatson.Emote background
$ flatpak permission-show com.tomjwatson.Emote
```

Note: I expected to get the same `flatpak permission-show` output as at the top (having used Flatseal) if I hit a working command - I didn't check Flatseal or manually test if the app can run in the background.

**Should I instead be using `flatpak override`?**

**What am I doing wrong?**